# Insert Blank Keyframe with Grease Pencil not working + Time Offset Modifier

Tags: modifiers, keyframes, grease-pencil, dopesheet, layers

I created a basic walk cycle in Grease Pencil and with time modifier looped it.
Now that I am trying to insert blank keyframes to the same to terminate it, and work again in the same layer it is not possible.

Despite inserting blank keyframe the loop does not disappear. How do I stop the time offset loop and get a blank keyframe?

Comment: A possible way is using Grease Pencil with the NLA editor as described [HERE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219547/102048)

Answer (score 1):

This Q was a result of a FLASH mindset where I can cut the loops as I wished.
Apparently in GP we cannot make these loops and cut as wish.

So, I copy pasted the frames as many times as needed, not the most beautiful solution but it works.