# Run a Grease Pencil loop multiple times and then change position

Tags: grease-pencil

I would like to run a walking cycle with Grease Pencil (Blender 2.9) a number of times. When my character reaches his destination, I want him to change position and do something else.

I know I can run the walking cycle using a Time Offset modifier on the Grease Pencil object. However, I have not figured out to set a number of finite repetitions.

Moreover, if I try to draw a new frame after using the Time Offset modifier, the new drawing does not erase the previous one.

I tried using the Non-Linear Animation NLA tool for this, using the suggestion [HERE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219547/102048), which allows me to loop a fixed number of times. However, I still cannot figure out how to continue with my animation, after the walk cycle has ended.

I have the feeling I am not using Grease Pencil properly for this task, and I would be grateful for guidance to the right approach.

Comment: You just keyframe the modifier ON then keyframe it OFF (both the eye and the camera icons).

Comment: Thank you for another useful answer. It was not obvious to me that I could keyframe those buttons. Now it makes sense. I am happy to accept this as an answer with a few more details.

Comment: How exactly do you keyframe an entire modifier to be either all the way on, or all the way off? There seems to be a way to do that with constraints, but not modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wilks wrote in a comment, the solution is to keyframe the time offset modifier as indicated below

[image]