# How to make multiple independent animations with grease pencil for character creation?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil

I'm trying to understand the workflow with the Grease Pencil and have stumbled across a fundamental problem that I haven't been able to solve yet. I am trying to create a 2D face that I project onto a 3D model using a shrink wrap modifier. Basically Im doing something like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7o5JGXU-V2Y) video. Starting from a base facial expression, I want to create several different expressions (laughing, crying, etc). How can I organize different animations using the Grease Pencil? I don't really want to create a face Rig. Can I solve this somehow with the Action Editor? I would really appreciate any hints.

Comment: well, action strips would be the answer in theory, but it doesn't work with greasepencil (GP frames just don't show up in the action editor). I've come up with a workaround but it's a tad complicated: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219221/how-to-use-nonlinear-animation-nla-editor-with-grease-pencil/219547#219547

Comment: @wilks I think that's the best thing to do given the current state of the art. Thanks for the comment. If you put that in a small reply (possibly referencing your reply in the link provided), then I will accept it. Otherwise, in a few days I will answer my own question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the perfect tool to do this is the Non-Linear Action editor. Problem is, greasepencil frames don't show up in the action editor which means you can't combine them into action strips. Hopefully one day it'll be implemented.

In the meantime, I've come up with the workaround I described here:
[How to use Nonlinear Animation NLA Editor with Grease Pencil](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219221/how-to-use-nonlinear-animation-nla-editor-with-grease-pencil/219547#219547). The gist is to keyframe a time offset modifier to pass over your animation, then push those keyframes to an action strip.