# Graphic symbol like in Adobe Animate

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

Does Blender have a built in feature or any addons for something like Adobe Animate's graphic symbol? It is like a thing where it has its own timeline inside, so for example:

I draw a man running in position then save it as a graphic symbol, now when I drop this graphic symbol in the main timeline I just need to do the tweening or in Blender it's called interpolation.

Comment: NLA strips might be close: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219221/how-to-use-nonlinear-animation-nla-editor-with-grease-pencil